# More succinct way to get Scanner input with error checking?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Just want to know if there was any better way of doing this since it's a lot of writing.

```java
boolean isInputValid = false;
do {
    System.out.print("Input: ");
    final String input = sc.nextLine();

    try {
        age = Integer.parseInt(input);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again");
        continue;
    }

    if (input < 0 || 10 < input) {
        System.out.println("Number outside of range.");
    } else {
        isInputValid = true;
    }
} while (!isInputValid);
```

Comment: At the moment this code would not compile. Furthermore, I think it should be posted in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ because code reviews are usually done there.

Comment: What I can think about is `sc.nextInt()` and then catch `InputMismatchException`, you will save one line :) But for sure you should separate the whole input reading into a separate method `int readInput()`. Your variable `isInputValid` has not usage by the way :)

Comment: Sorry, age should be input, I misttyped that because I was erasing some stuff before pasting the code, and I don't see how I can edit the original post

Comment: @HonzaZidek the only reason I don't use nextInt() is that if you have some weird input like " fdsa  fdsa 324 " that's just completely random it will do some weird stuff on the next iteration so I just used nextLine instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are some things that can be ommited on a first look, but there is not much to remove.

- Reduced integer parsing in a single line and removed `input` variable.
- Change `isInputValid` to its negation  `isInputInvalid` to remove else , Boolean assignment and negation in the `while` clause.
- Moved `if` into the `try` clause to make redundant and remove the `continue` statement.

```java
boolean isInputInvalid = true;
do {
    System.out.print("Input: ");
    try {
        age = Integer.parseInt(  sc.nextLine());
        isInputInvalid = input < 0 || 10 < input;
        if (isInputInvalid) {
           System.out.println("Number outside of range.");
        } 
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again");
    }
  
} while (isInputInvalid);
```

Comment: I see you've included most of the logic in the try block, is that better practice than having it outside the try block? I was under the impression that I should only have the thing I am testing for exceptions inside the try block

Comment: It is evident that the only thing that can generate the NumberFormatException is the parseInt call, so in this case brevity wins.  Most rules need interpretation.

Comment: In this case it helps make the code more succinct. As passer-by already mentioned,in this case only the 'parseInt' call could throw the NumberFormatException. So the `try-catch` still catches the sam Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Well by first glance, I can see that you're comparing an incorrect variable  type of string with an integer (your input variable), I'm just going to assume that you meant to compare the age. You should also put the if statements within your try/catch to ensure that its handled as intended (there's also no point in having it outside the try/catch if a NFE is thrown, it won't get ran anyways).

```
boolean isInputValid = true;
do {
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            final String input = sc.nextLine();

            try {
                age = Integer.parseInt(input);

                if (age < 0 || 10 < age) {
                    System.out.println("Number outside of range.");
                    isInputValid = false;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again");
                continue;
            }
        } while (isInputValid);
```

Comment: I see, so put logic inside try, got it. Thank you.